# What is the best method to rotate an xarray dataset by n degrees?

Tags: python, scipy, python-xarray

I would like to rotate a data array that is in lat lon coordinates by n degrees.

I have tried using the scipy ndimage.rotate function (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.rotate.html):

```
import xarray as xr
from scipy import ndimage

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
da = airtemps['air'][0]

test = xr.apply_ufunc(ndimage.rotate,da,10,(1,0),False)
test[::5,::5].plot(vmin=220,vmax=300)
```

This works well for the small dataset here, but when I try to use a dataset with lat lon dimensions of 4200 x 4200 it assigns everything as np.nan. It works for a small subset of my data (with dimensions up to 300 x 300), so I think it's a limit to the function capability, rather than to the way I'm using it.

I've not been able to find a native xarray method for rotating images. Is there another method that would be more appropriate to use?